# Plus sign in GET query and compare URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to check the current URL of the page if include + sign in the query if there is no + sign I will rewrite the URL and 301 redirect to a new one.. for example

```
www.sitename.com/search?q=123 456
```

this should be

```
www.sitename.com/search?q=123+456
```

First I was thinking to make this with PHP, first, `$_GET['q']` and clean string, replace space with + and compare with the current one `$_GET['q']` in URL but the problem is because I can't get + sign in `$_GET` and simple I can't check if URL include + sign
.

Another option is to make this with **.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^search$ test.php?mode=search&q=%1 [L]
```

But I believe this can be better done with PHP because there is more query parameter that isn't just `q`

Some ideas were

```
    $q1 = cleanq($_GET['q']) //This query include +,cleanq is function to clean string and replace space with +
    $q2 = $_GET['q'] //This is current one
    if(strcmp($q1, $q2) != 0){
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("Location: www.sitename.com/search?q=".$q1);
        exit();
    }
```

Looks simple but can't get the sign-in query to compare, any idea how to make this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the URL specification, the character `+` in URLs must be interpreted as a space, as plain spaces are not allowed in URLs.

You don't have to worry about redirecting `www.sitename.com/search?q=123 456` to `www.sitename.com/search?q=123+456`, it's the same link.

You can do a simple test in a PHP file:

`test.php?search1=aaa bbb&search2=aaa+bbb`

```
if ($_GET['search1'] == $_GET['search2']) {
    print 'Same string!';
}
```

You'll get `Same string!`

---

If you want to update the current URL you can do it with javascript, by replacing the encoded url space `%20` with `+`

```
<script>
    const url = window.location.href.replace(/%20/, "+");
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, url)
</script>
```

---

PHP redirect using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

```
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '%20') !== false) {
    $request_uri = str_replace('%20', '+', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $request_uri = preg_replace('/([+])\1+/', '$1', $request_uri);

    if ($request_uri != $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("Location: " . $request_uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know is actually same but I want to make this part of site clean, as I can see YouTube and most of site which I visits do same things it replace space with +

Comment: Youtube, if you check, it doesn't redirect, it replaces the URL after the page load from space to `+`. I guess is using javascript. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes JavaScript, I give you just one of example, most of site do same, some with JavaScript some with php or webaserver. So looks solutions is only in Apache and .htaccess to remove all special characters and space and replace with + {QUERY_STRING}, with php looks is not possible

Comment: I saw JavaScript code but is not what i need, i need 301 redirection, google has indexed both pages one with the + and one with the " " space, and WMT complains of duplicate content that's why i need to redirect it

Comment: I updated with a version for PHP using REQUEST_URI

Comment: Hmm this promising I will try now, there will be problem if URL contain space few times, str_replace will replace just one space as i can see, goings to try in few minutes

Comment: It will replace every space that you have in URL.

Comment: Yes It's working but problem with multiple space if i have query `q=test     test` it will be replaced with `q=test++++test` but should be `q=test+test`

Comment: I updated the answer with a preg_replace. Now a string like zzz+++aaa++cc will be like  zzz+aaa+cc

Comment: Yes that is all, looks it's working fine. Thank you, all this time I was going the wrong way, instead of $_SERVER I was playing with with $_GET and query only.